# What is expected behavior when Testcafe clicks on a disabled button or type text into readonly input

Tags: automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation, web-testing

What is the expected behavior of the Testcafe in those two cases:

1. await t.click(Button with 'disabled` parameter)
2. await t.typeText(Input with 'readonly' parameter)

Should Testcafe throw an error or just skip actions? Currently, in those cases, Testcafe just skips those steps and move forward.

I know that I can use something like

`await t.expect(input.hasAttribute('readonly').notOk().typeText(input,'text');`

It would be very helpful if Testcafe automatically does this verification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skipping actions with disabled/readonly elements is the expected behavior.

I agree that in some scenarios it makes sense to verify that the target element is enabled and writable. However, actions with disabled/readonly elements are not technically invalid, and they may be intended in certain test cases.

I have created an issue on GitHub for further discussion: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4106.